# paypal IPN php script- mysql not working?

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, paypal, paypal-ipn

I took the standard IPN.php sample from paypal, added error handling and mysqlconnection/mysqlquery to the php script. I believe their might be an issue with the variables coming into the ipn script and then being stored in mysql db. Mysql db connection works fine. I really think its code with mysql query, but I don't know how to change it.  Any help would be awesome!

Error via ipn_errors.log

```
[21-Jan-2013 13:45:57 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: item_number in /var/www/ipn.php on line 78
[21-Jan-2013 13:45:57 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: payment_status in /var/www/ipn.php on line 78
[21-Jan-2013 13:45:57 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: payment_amount in /var/www/ipn.php on line 78
[21-Jan-2013 13:45:57 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: payer_email in /var/www/ipn.php on line 78
```

ipn.php- that is creating these errors.

```
// STEP 1: Read POST data

// reading posted data from directly from $_POST causes serialization 
// issues with array data in POST
// reading raw POST data from input stream instead. 
mysql_connect("localhost", "#####", "#####") or die(mysql_error());  
mysql_select_db("#####") or die(mysql_error()); 
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
$keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
if (count($keyval) == 2)
 $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
   $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
} 
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {        
if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
} else {
    $value = urlencode($value);
}
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}


// STEP 2: Post IPN data back to paypal to validate

$ch = curl_init('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

// In wamp like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
// please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path 
// of the certificate as shown below.
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
// error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
curl_close($ch);
exit;
}
curl_close($ch);


// STEP 3: Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
// check whether the payment_status is Completed
// check that txn_id has not been previously processed
// check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
// check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
// process payment

// assign posted variables to local variables
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
// log for manual investigation
 ini_set('log_errors', true);
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__).'/ipn_errors.log');
}
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO paypalpayments (itemnum, paystatus, payamount, email) VALUES ('', '$item_number', 

'$payment_status', '$payment_amount',  '$payer_email')");
?>
```

Comment: those are notices, not errors,  it should still actully work - does it?

Comment: No. Maybe something wrong with mysql code. Is there a way to output the POST to a text file, instead of mysql db so I can test with out mysql ? Sorry I am a vb.net/asp guy, but I have to use a linux server with LAMP.

Answer (score 1):

The variables are set in this line:

```
$myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
```

... and later in the script it uses `$_POST` to copy variables like this:

```
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
```

Suggestion: use `$myPost` instead of `$_POST` to locate these variables.  And don't forget mysql_real_escape_string() before the INSERT query.

You can make some progress debugging this asynchronous script if you use `ob_start()` at the top and `$msg = ob_get_clean()` at the end.  Then you have a variable string you can email to yourself.  That will enable you to use `var_dump()`, etc., to issue diagnostic messages.

Comment: I don't know how to use ob_start. I'll look it up a little later. I did make the correction based on your suggestion, however I am still getting the same notification. Is there a way to output the POST to a text file, instead of mysql db so I can test with out mysql ?